# Node syntax reference

Tags: node.js, react-native, render, notation

I have the following render function:

```
render() {

    var items = this.props.items;
    var lists = this.props.lists;
    var addItem = this.props.addItem;
    return (
      <div key={uuidv4()}>
      {lists.map(function(listName) {
        return (
         <List name={listName} items={items[listName]} addItem={addItem.bind(this)} key={uuidv4()} />
          )
        })
       }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

could some provide a reference for the {} that surrounds the map function. I can't seem to find where to look.  Do you just use that notation to execute inside the return of render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a node.js or javascript but a JSX syntax

> You can pass any JavaScript expression as children, by enclosing it within {}

[Here is documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-children)